# apache drill query with SQL like column name

Tags: apache-drill

I have a problem in querying a CSV (with header) file using Drill.
If I run the following code:

```
SELECT Bid, Last FROM table(dfs.`/data/bb_20020201.csv` (type => 'text', fieldDelimiter => ',', extractHeader => true));
```

I got an error code corresponding to the word "Last". If I query another column instead of Last everything works nice.
I think the problem is because Last is also a SQL command.

I would really appreciate any help on this issue.

Comment: Did below answer resolved your issue ? Please let us know.

Answer (score 1):

It seems Last is reserved keyword in Drill. Enclose it in a back-ticks:

```
SELECT Bid, `Last` FROM ...
```

https://drill.apache.org/docs/lexical-structure/#identifiers

Or change identifier quotes to double quotes or brackets if you need:
https://drill.apache.org/docs/lexical-structure/#identifier-quotes

If it helps you, you can create a Jira ticket to add `Last` to reserved keywords table:
https://drill.apache.org/docs/reserved-keywords/